# How to split downloads and make threads for faster speed in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, macos, swift

so i want to increase my download speed in my app, but i can seem to find any library for swift, all is for objective c only. im currently using Alamofire for downloads but it doesnt have the feauture of multi thread downloading and file segmenting.

Is there any library that i can refer to or whats the best approach to this issue ?
Thanks for your help. cheers